# OpenId authentification in ASP.NET MVC as a restful service?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-2, authentication, rest, openid

Can I offer the authentication, authorization, etc created using "ASP.NET MVC Open Id website" extension.. as a REST service in ASP.NET MVC? How can I create this service(maybe using WCF)? 
(Please if you can, offer me some examples please).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can.  OpenID is *not* about authorizing web services at all.  That's what OAuth does.  But DotNetOpenAuth does both OpenID and OAuth, so your users can authenticate with OpenID, then authorize RESTful clients via OAuth, and the user story is probably exactly what you're looking for.

There is a [project template that shows you exactly how to do it](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/81153747-70d7-477b-b85a-0374e7edabef) (does it for you, actually) available on the Visual Studio Gallery.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create REST services using just MVC.  WCF is not necessary.  There are tons of posts on restful architecture in ASP.NET MVC.

There is code available with a base API for Restful services using ASP.NET MVC available here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/MvcWebAPI .

The author of this library has an excellent article explaining how to create such a service that is capable of will serve both JSON and XML.  It can be read at: http://omaralzabir.com/create_rest_api_using_asp_net_mvc_that_speaks_both_json_and_plain_xml/

There are plenty of tools that can help you implement the OpenId service, such as http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/ or the solution outlined at http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/899303.aspx.  You said you've already created an OpenId logging system.  Basically, take the logging system, create an interface like:

```
 public interface IOpenIdService{
      bool Login(string login, string password);
 }
```

and execute it in your Controller Action method.  If it is successful return a JSON or XML success message.  If it fails return a JSON or XML failure message.

*I have also found this article helpful for REST with MVC: http://blog.wekeroad.com/2007/12/06/aspnet-mvc-using-restful-architecture/.  Also, if you want to extend JSON functionality, look into JSON.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the latest nerddinner tutorial on codeplex.  It has OpenId integration built into the MVC example application: http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

Comment: maybe you don't understand me.. I already have Open Id logging system, but I want to offer it as a rest service using something like WCF.